# Name of the Android Notification's First Alert?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

It may sound a weird question at first but I want to learn the name of the first alert in Android so that I can research how it is done.

What I mean is, for example, while you are talking to some person on WhatsApp, some other person or group sends you a message and you are firstly alerted on top of the screen for a few seconds (which is directly clickable) and then that notification takes its place back on the notification bar, meaning you have to scroll down this time to reach.

How can I search this? Or, if anyone has any tutorial about how to implement it, I'd appreciate much.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its called Heads-up Notification.

refer this [link](http://www.brevitysoftware.com/how-to-get-heads-up-notifications-in-android/)